# removing and storing list from dictionary

Tags: python

In python, 
I have a dictionary composed of the following:

```
[ ['FOXP2_MOUSE', 'AminoAcidSequence1'], ['FOXP2_RAT','AminoAcidSequence2'], ['FOXP2_DOG', 'AminoAcidSequence3'] ].
```

I'm trying to remove the keyed `FOXP2_DOG` from the dictionary and place it in a new dictionary alone. I've tried different methods: `del` and `.remove` to no avail.

Comment: That's not a dict, it's a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
>>> my_list= [ ['FOXP2_MOUSE', 'AminoAcidSequence1'], ['FOXP2_RAT','AminoAcidSequence2'], ['FOXP2_DOG', 'AminoAcidSequence3'] ]
>>> my_dict = dict(my_list)
>>> my_dict
{'FOXP2_RAT': 'AminoAcidSequence2', 'FOXP2_MOUSE': 'AminoAcidSequence1', 'FOXP2_DOG': 'AminoAcidSequence3'}
>>> my_new_dict = {}
>>> my_new_dict['FOXP2_MOUSE'] = my_dict.pop('FOXP2_MOUSE')
>>> my_dict
{'FOXP2_RAT': 'AminoAcidSequence2', 'FOXP2_DOG': 'AminoAcidSequence3'}
>>> my_new_dict
{'FOXP2_MOUSE': 'AminoAcidSequence1'}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP wants to remove `'FOXP2_DOG'` and place it in a new dict.

Comment: And still not right. `NameError: name 'my_new_dict' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

```
my_data = [ ['FOXP2_MOUSE', 'AminoAcidSequence1'], ['FOXP2_RAT','AminoAcidSequence2'], ['FOXP2_DOG', 'AminoAcidSequence3'] ]

def custom_filter_data(data, key): 

    final_res = []

    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i][0] == key:
            final_res.append(data[i])
            del data[i]

    return data, final_res

results = custom_filter_data(my_data,'FOXP2_DOG')
old = results[0]
new = results[1]
print old
print new
```

Comment: @jaimed_2003 Glad it was of help, can you mark this answer accepted if you found this most useful ?